# Seleccionar ítem de un jCombobox ya cargado, por su ID (de la tabla BD) y no por su index y lo muestre

Tags: java, java-swing

¿Cómo llenar un `jCombobox` y cargar un valor?

| id | Nombre |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | A+ |
| 20 | A- |
| 31 | B+ |
| 44 | B- |

Los registros ya los tengo cargados en el jCombobox, eso sí funciona bien. Tengo una caja de texto y un botón de buscar.

Por ejemplo, si coloco en la caja de texto *44* y presiono el botón buscar, quiero que me seleccione automáticamente *B-* en el combo y me lo muestre.

Al combo lo lleno de esta forma:

```
 cmbSanguineo.removeAllItems();
 lista_modsanguineo = (ArrayList<modsanguineo>) mant_SanguineoCtrl.listarSanguineo();
 DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel(lista_modsanguineo.toArray());
 this.cmbSanguineo.setModel(model);
```

Estoy intentando mostrarlo en el registro buscado por su ID de esta forma:

Botón buscar:

```
  for (int i = 0; i<cmbSanguineo.getItemCount(); i++){
        ** if (modsanguineo.getIdSanguineo().equals(txtcodigo.getText())) {**
        cmbSanguineo.setSelectedIndex(i);     
         }
    }
```

Me da error en la linea del IF, al parecer son por los tipos de datos.

Comment: Pulsá en [edit] y mostrá el error que te aparece.

Comment: Dónde estás almacenando los id junto al nombre que quieres buscar?
Por otro lado, no sé si lo estoy entendiendo mal, pero "modsanguineo" es una clase, y luego en el if llamas a su método estático que te devuelve el ID, para compararlo? En todo caso, ese if siempre será true o siempre false, no varía nada en cada iteración del bucle. Tal vez se te haya escapado algo por ahí. Si podrías aclarar un poco más tal vez te sea de más ayuda

Comment: Muchas Gracias Francisco, "Dónde estás almacenando los id junto al nombre que quieres buscar? " te  refieres como lleno mi  Jcombox  bueno hasta donde tengo entendido id y nombre se guardan como objetos en combo --- pero lo resolvi de otra forma .

Comment: Si has conseguido resolverlo, deberías de añadir la respuesta a tu propia pregunta y marcarla como solución, ya que puede aparecer otro usuario con el mismo problema, o un problema similar.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal logre  resolverlo de esta forma  cree un metodo :setSelectedValue
lo tuve que convertir a string  para utilizar el metrodo  equalsIgnoreCase

```
introducir el código aquí

public void setSelectedValue(JComboBox comboBox, String value)**
    {
        modDepartamento item;
        for (int i = 0; i < comboBox.getItemCount(); i++)
        {
            item = (modsanguineo)comboBox.getItemAt(i);
            if (Integer.toString(item.getIdSanguineo()).equalsIgnoreCase(value))
            { 
                comboBox.setSelectedIndex(i);
                break;                
            }
        }
  }
```

y lo llamo el metodo enviando los parametros desde mi boton

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

   setSelectedValue( cmbSanguineo,txtcodigo.getText().toString().trim());
}
```